# How to perform actions on create/save/delete for entities implementing interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a couple of entities that have an index field that I use to specify which order to display the records in. This field is an integer, and it must go from 1 to n without any "holes" (can't have 1,2,4,5). In order to maintain the index fields I need to do the following:

- On **Add** the index field should be set so that the new record is placed last
- On **Edit**, if the index has changed, the records in between the old and the new index  of the edited record need to be updated
- On **Delete** the records having an higher index than the one being deleted need to be updated

So, what I'm wondering is, instead of defining this behavior once for each class that is "sortable", can I do it in a more generic way? Ie. performing these actions for entities that implements an interface, ISortable?

Where should this logic be placed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like an (abstract) base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement the interface in partial classes that exist alongside your POCOs (or inherit from an abstract base class) and you centralise the updating in your `Context` class that inherits from `DbContext` or as a Decorator to `DbContext`. You'll need to implement your own abstraction (for example `IUnitOfWork`) because `DbContext` does not implement any useful interfaces.

Here's a simple example that is implemented inside the `Context`:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach(IAuditData item in GetChangedAuditDataEntities())
    {
        //...... update the entity
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}


private IEnumerable<IAuditData> GetChangedAuditDataEntities()
{
    return (
        from entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged
        select entry)
        .OfType<IAuditData>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually thinking of doing something similar, centralizing the common logic in the Context class. But I was unsure if this was the best way of doing it. I guess I was looking for a more "modular" way, so that the DbContext class doesn't get bloated. I could of course put the logic in a separate class, and call it from DbContext.

Comment: The correct way would be to use a decorator. See here http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91 for example